# Print all rows from one table with a nested MySQL query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a MySQL query that I would like to enhance by requiring that all values of client.client_name are printed out in the result, even if no values are found for every row in that table. The current table shows:

```
client.client_name
Client A
Client B
Client C
```

The current MySQL query is below:

```
    SELECT X.expr1 AS 'Project Name', SUM(X.expr2) AS 'Total Hours Logged', X.expr3 - sum(X.expr2) AS 'Monthly Hours Remaining', X.expr4 AS 'Last Day', DATEDIFF(X.expr4 , curdate()) AS 'Days Remaining'
FROM 
(SELECT 
    client.client_name AS expr1
    , sum(time_records.value) AS expr2
    , client.monthly_hours AS expr3
FROM project_objects
  INNER JOIN projects
    ON projects.id = project_objects.project_id
  INNER JOIN time_records
    ON time_records.parent_id = project_objects.id
  LEFT JOIN client  
  ON project_objects.project_id = client.project_id 
  WHERE time_records.parent_type = 'Task' 
  AND client.start_day_of_month < dayofmonth(curdate())
  AND time_records.state = 3
  GROUP BY client.client_name

  UNION

  SELECT 
    client.client_name AS expr1
    , sum(time_records.value) as expr2
    , client.monthly_hours AS expr3
  FROM projects
  INNER JOIN time_records
    ON projects.id = time_records.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN client  
   ON projects.id = client.project_id 
  WHERE time_records.parent_type = 'Project'
  AND client.start_day_of_month < dayofmonth(curdate())
  AND time_records.state = 3
  GROUP BY client.client_name
) X
GROUP BY X.expr1
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(X.expr4 , curdate()
```

As you can see from the above query - I added a Left Join for the client table, however it doesn't result in printing out all client records - it only prints those for which there are time_records available. I think this is related to the nesting or the order of how I am writing the joins, but can't seem to figure it out. If you have any ideas it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try order as below:

```
FROM client LEFT JOIN project_objects 
    ON project_objects.project_id = client.project_id
```

see SQLFiddle for the final solution here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30362/16

Comment: That seems to be on the right track - however now the numbers for Sum(X.expr2) aren't adding up correctly. I think that there needs to be a SELECT statement to calculate the time nested somewhere within a join, now that there is a left join. Any tips?

Comment: Running only the UNION query ( ie the inner subquery), is the result retrieved correctly? Suggest to run the query step by step in order to find out what is the issue.

Comment: Each query works individually (inner subqueries). Actually I added the code you suggested inside each inner subquery. Should I instead be adding it somewhere else? If so, where should it be added?

Comment: I meant if you run only SELECT xxxxxxx UNION SELECT xxxxxx as in your query (with the modified left join as suggested), do all the records returned correctly? Have to make sure the records returned correctly before the sum(expr2) could be returned correctly.

Comment: no - they are not correct. Actually my comment about the sum(x.expr2) being incorrect should have stated that the subquery sum(time_records.value) were not calculating correctly after I added the Left Join to the subquery. The sum(time_records.value) are coming out higher than they should be.

Comment: Mind give some sample data at sqlfiddle.com for me to take a look?

Comment: Thank you for the offer to help - I have created the sample data at the link here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47fd4/10 . On the right side is my original query. If you can suggest where to put the left join to make it print Client C that would be great.

Comment: Hi - I just tested this and added a new Client to the client table ("Client Empty"), to see if the query would return this client in spite of having no time_record, but it does not show the new client. The fiddle is here (only update was inserting a new client  to the table in the schema builder (last line). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab1fc/2 .

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab1fc/13  found out its due to the group by. Have to group by client.client_name since there could be null value for acx_projects.name.

Comment: that's closer, but now the acx_time_records.value (Total Hours Logged) are not adding up correctly: Client A should be 5 and Client B should be 10, as in the SQLfiddle example - however Client B is now showing as 15.

Comment: that is due to the second union. If you run the union separately (ie without the union), u will see the value return in second union is 5 for client b which then sum to the first union and result 15 for client b. I am not sure what is the purpose for your second union.

Comment: I see the issue - I tried to simplify the query for the purpose of the sqlfiddle and took out the "Where" line - I added that back in to the fiddle so you can see the issue I am having. The Where clause includes 2 versions for parent_type for the acx_time_records, one for each union statement (that's why I had to use a union). Now it's only showing results for one client

Comment: for the parent type, may i know the reason you are not using OR in the where condition?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18507/discussion-between-sel-and-daniel-c)